# thumbnail scroller inside div with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im using a jquery scroller for my photography website which i cannot get it to work. Im using these two files:

**main.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>   
<body>
<input name="activator" type="button" value="Click me" onClick="show()"/>
<div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }   
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","thumbs.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**and also thumbs.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jquery.thumbnailScroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tS2" class="jThumbnailScroller">
<div class="jTscrollerContainer">
<div class="jTscroller">
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
<a href=#><img src="xxxxxx"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>      

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
window.onload=function(){
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
        scrollerType:"hoverPrecise",
        scrollerOrientation:"horizontal",
        scrollSpeed:2,
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
        scrollEasingAmount:600,
        acceleration:4,
        scrollSpeed:800,
        noScrollCenterSpace:10,
        autoScrolling:0,
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
        autoScrollingDelay:500
    });
}
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

AJAX is loaded fine. Everything else looks fine. The problem here is that the div content is simply not scrollable. It shows everything correct but the div content is nor arranged or scrollable as it's shown in:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller (the source for the code)

The problem lies in the use of AJAX to load my content (which is mandatory) but i do not have the knowledge to work this problem out. Anyone can help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

**AFTER ALL THE ANSWERS, HERE IS THE WORKING CODE(thanks to @Abhidev):**

**main.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="thumbnail_gallery/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
<link href="thumbnail_gallery/jquery.thumbnailScroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="thumbnail_gallery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<input name="activator" type="button" value="Click me" onClick="show()"/>
    <div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{    
    $.ajax({
          url: "TESTE.php",
          success: function(data) {
             $('#display').html(data);
            //Initiate the scroller here
            $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
                scrollerType:"hoverPrecise",
                scrollerOrientation:"horizontal",
                scrollSpeed:2,
                scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
                scrollEasingAmount:600,
                acceleration:4,
                scrollSpeed:800,
                noScrollCenterSpace:10,
                autoScrolling:0,
                autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
                autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
                autoScrollingDelay:500
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**thumbs.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="thumbnail_gallery/jquery.thumbnailScroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="thumbnail_gallery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thumbnail_gallery/jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tS2" class="jThumbnailScroller">
<div class="jTscrollerContainer">
<div class="jTscroller">
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="1.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.7. You need to use it. Even the example that you sent over uses 1.7.

Comment: if you are using jquery, why are you not using `.ajax()`, which abstracts away from all of that horrible AJAX code you have there

Comment: Ohgodwhy -Thank you for the pointer, but it still doesn't make it work.
@Chimoo - Im still new to this and don't know how to implement JQUERY AJAX.

Comment: prehaps you could setup a jsfiddle - its always easier for us to tinker and then give you a solution that works than to guess from what you've written here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using jquery, then simply you can make use of the .ajax() method

```
function show(){    
    $.ajax({
          url: "thumbs.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $('#display').html(data);       //Here is the change
            //Initiate the scroller here
            $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
                scrollerType:"hoverPrecise",
                scrollerOrientation:"horizontal",
                scrollSpeed:2,
                scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",
                scrollEasingAmount:600,
                acceleration:4,
                scrollSpeed:800,
                noScrollCenterSpace:10,
                autoScrolling:0,
                autoScrollingSpeed:2000,
                autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad",
                autoScrollingDelay:500
            });
        });

    }
```

Refer thsi for more details and options http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I load the Jquery script from:
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

and put the funtion in the end of the body like this:
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){  
.......
</script>

but now AJAX does not display anything... Help, please. Sorry for the noobing...

Comment: When i click on the button on the main.php file.

Comment: oops sorry, I have updated my answer, forgot to display the response. :P

Comment: Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$' is not a function
Error thrown at line 9, column 12 in <anonymous function: success>(data) in http://localhost/SITE%20FOTOGRAFIA/TESTING.php:
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 2, column 29466 in <anonymous function: f.Callbacks>(b, f) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    if(c[l].apply(b,f)===!1&&a.stopOnFalse)

Comment: called from line 2, column 31004 in <anonymous function: fireWith>(b, c) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    d&&(i?a.once||d.push([b,c]):(!a.once||!e)&&n(b,c));
called from line 4, column 22304 in w(a, c, l, m) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    v.status=a,v.statusText=""+(c||w),o?h.resolveWith(e,[r,w,v]):h.rejectWith(e,[v,w,u]),v.statusCode(j),j=b,t&&g.trigger("ajax"+(o?"Success":"Error"),[v,d,o?r:u]),i.fireWith(e,[v,w]),t&&(g.trigger("ajaxComplete",

Comment: [v,d]),--f.active||f.event.trigger("ajaxStop"))
called from line 4, column 34041 in <anonymous function: d>(a, e) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:
    m&&g(j,k,m,l)

Comment: add the jquery file in the head and make sure that your show() function is defined after the jquery.js include

Comment: You're the best! Thank you very much! The problem was that I was duplicating the function in thumbs.php. So, by eliminating it and using your code, it worked just fine!

Comment: Glad your problem was solved :). For any javascript debugging you can make use of firebug(firefox extension)