# Bind jQuery function after ajax call

Tags: jquery

Ok, I've been trying to get this to work for a few days now. I have a thumbnail scroller and it works fine when the window is loaded with the provide code below. But after the ajax call it does not.

this is the function loaded initially.

```
    (function($){
     window.onload=function(){ 
    $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
        scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
        scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
        scrollSpeed:2, 
        scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
        scrollEasingAmount:800, 
        acceleration:4, 
        scrollSpeed:800, 
        noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
        autoScrolling:0, 
        autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
        autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
        autoScrollingDelay:500 
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

I tried adding this to part below in my ajax function call back but still doesn't work.

```
$("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
            scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
            scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
            scrollSpeed:2, 
            scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
            scrollEasingAmount:800, 
            acceleration:4, 
            scrollSpeed:800, 
            noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
            autoScrolling:0, 
            autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
            autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
            autoScrollingDelay:500 
        });
    }
```

How do I reinitialize this or is there some way to use On? The problem is the ID/element is not loaded until the ajax call is done, then I need to reattach the thumbnailScoller function. BTW I do a click to do the ajax call which already uses .On but placing this function in there doesn't work. Any help is welcomed.

Edit: Here is the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax.php",
            data: {"pho_id": pho_id, "alb_id": alb_id},
            success: function(response){
                $("#phoajax").html(response);
                $("#tS2").thumbnailScroller({ 
                scrollerType:"clickButtons", 
                scrollerOrientation:"horizontal", 
                scrollSpeed:2, 
                scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
                scrollEasingAmount:800, 
                acceleration:4, 
                scrollSpeed:800, 
                noScrollCenterSpace:10, 
                autoScrolling:0, 
                autoScrollingSpeed:2000, 
                autoScrollingEasing:"easeInOutQuad", 
                autoScrollingDelay:500 
                });
                pslide(alb_id);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole ajax call?

Comment: So, the assumption is that the response is formatted HTML, and it contains a tag with `id="tS2"`? I would say, check with FireBug or the Chrome dev panel to make sure the HTML is being set as you expect.

Comment: It is. The call shows the div and all the actual img tags with the thunmbs but it doesn't show in the slider. Only when it's loaded from a window refresh. So the html is there. This should be very simple. lol

Comment: It may be that adding the HTML causes the browser to have to fetch all of the images, but you're calling the .thumbnailScroller() immediately after the ajax returns. Try putting http://api.jquery.com/delay/ into the code. `$.delay(5000); $("#ts2")...`

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I was calling the thumbnailScoller before pslide(), that is why it broke. Put humbnailScoller() last and viola! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call it in the callback function of the ajax call, not after it:

```
$.post("some_url", {var: var1 .... etc}, function(data){ //the same with $.ajax, $.get
     //HERE !
});
```

the callback function is executed after your ajax call is done, if you modified or added any DOM elements with the ajax call you need to apply the jquery functions after that modification.

Comment: I actually tried that and somehow it won't bind correctly as it still doesn't work. That's the first thing I tried. I just found this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844586/thumbnail-scroller-inside-div-with-ajax?rq=1 and it worked for this person.

Comment: hmm pretty weird. try to do some `console.log()` of variables in the callback function to check if everything is correctly loaded. one common error is duplicated id's. If you add 2 elements with the same id and try to apply your jquery function to both of them using said id it won't work.

Comment: Yeah I don't see any dupes so far. It's weird. The ajax call is pulling the thumbs but won't bind it back to the div. Just don't get it.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer as it was what was needed but the order in which my callbacks was wrong. I figured it out.